# RoR: Collection_select not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

**UPDATED**

The official docs for this are not the best and a little confusing. I am gathering options from a feedback table and rendering them in a dropdown on a form and then saving them in a table called "answers" and column called "feedback_request" using collection_select:

```
<%= f.collection_select :feedback_request, Feedback.order(:feedback_option), :id, :feedback_request, {prompt: "Feedback"}, {class: "select large-1 behaviourForm"} %>
```

Answers table:

```
  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer  "user_id",             limit: 4
        t.string   "subject",             limit: 4
        t.string   "source",              limit: 45
        t.text     "description",         limit: 65535
        t.string   "significance",        limit: 45
        t.string   "feedback_request"
        t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    end

  add_index "answers", ["feedback_request"], name: "feedback_index"
  add_index "answers", ["significance"], name: "signif_index"
  add_index "answers", ["source"], name: "source_index"
  add_index "answers", ["subject"], name: "FK_HOM_MOD_idx"
  add_index "answers", ["user_id"], name: "teacher_answer_index"
```

Feedback table

```
create_table "feedback", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "feedback_option", limit: 45
  end
```

Relationships

feedback.rb

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'feedback'
    has_many :answers, :class_name => 'Answer'
end
```

answer.rb

```
belongs_to :feedback, :class_name => 'Feedback', :foreign_key => :feedback_request
```

Table (as requested):

```
         <thead>
              <tr>
                <% if current_user.teacher? %>
                <th style="width:5%;", bgcolor="#313E4E" ></th>
                <th bgcolor="#313E4E"><font color="#FFFFFF">Answer Title</font></th>
                <% else %>
                <th bgcolor="#313E4E"><font color="#FFFFFF">Subject</font></th>
                <% end %>
                <th bgcolor="#313E4E"><font color="#FFFFFF">Source</font></th>

                <th bgcolor="#313E4E"><font color="#FFFFFF"><%= sort_link(@q, :created_at, "Assigned/Scheduled") %></font></th>
                <th bgcolor="#313E4E"><font color="#FFFFFF"><%= sort_link(@q, :Due, "Due") %></font></th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
              </tfoot>
              <%= form_tag destroy_multiple_answers_path, method: :delete do %>
              <% @answers.each do |answer| %>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <% if current_user.teacher? %>
                <td><%= check_box_tag "answer[id][]", answer.id, class: "narrowtr" %></input></td>
                <td height="1"><font color="#000000"><%= link_to answer.subject, answer, class: "blackLink" %></font></td>
                <% else %>
                <td height="1"><%= answer.subject %></td>
                <% end %>
                <td height="1"></td>
                <td height="1"><%= answer.created_at %></td>
                <td height="1"><%= answer.Due %></td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              <% end %>
            </table>
```

This gives me the following error on submit:

```
**undefined method `feedback_request' for #<Feedback id: 1, feedback_option: "Curriculum Management">**
```

Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the table?

Comment: Hi, it's Active Admin. It shows up automatically. I tried adding feedback_id integer to table but this does not work either: <%= f.collection_select :feedback_id, Feedback.order(:feedback_option), :id, :feedback_request, {prompt: "Feedback"}, {class: "select large-1 behaviourForm"} %>. I get the following: "undefined method `feedback_request' for #<Feedback id: 1, feedback_option: "Curriculum Management">"

Comment: Ah - then that is something you probably should have included in your question somewhere :)
Also - if you are relying on ActiveAdmin's defaults and want to override them - then you can do that: http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html

Comment: Thanks but I don't get it. The feedback_request column is there and it is a string. It is not updating the record with this. I tested it. Doesn't work. :(

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I fully understand what you need. My guess at this is: you have a collection-select... which lets you select a set of "feedbacks" for your `Answer`, based on what they select in the drop-down... the drop-down correctly displays the display-column of `feedback-option` so you can select correctly... the values that come through from that to rails are the ids of the feedbacks (because the value of the select is `id`) and gets correctly stored in the database. but the next page (the index page) displays the ids instead of the feedback_options that you'd like to display.

Comment: If the above understanding is correct, then what you need to do is change the columns being displayed on the activeadmin index page for Answers... to the feedbacks-column you want displayed instead. If my understanding of what you want is not correct - can you please edit your question to reflect what you really want? :)

Comment: It's actually both. I want to display the name instead of id on both active admin and the table in my app. Currently both will display id only. The record is being saved but does not make sense presented like this. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, so that means what we need to see is the code that generates the table... you say this is active-admin for at least one of these... and to fix that, you need to override the default columns being displayed on the table (as per the link I gave you). if there is another table that is not active admin, then please update your question and add the relevant code there so I can help you alter that too.

Comment: Thanks! will update later today.

Comment: I have updated my question for more clarity.

Comment: Ok... so the collection-select is complaining that  Answer does not have the `feedback_request` column... does it? Can you confirm that this is a column on the `answers` table? have you double-checked that you're run the migration? :)